Can I create a 2nd generation package dependent on a 1GP, with the same namespace?
I was searching on the web but did not find exactly the answer (I think it is no).
I have a 1st generation package with a given namespace, and I would like to create a new package dependent on the first one. Ideally I would like to create it as a 2GP, with the same namespace, is this possible? It seems the answer is no from this link, but it doesn't say if the packages are dependent from each other.
Thank you.

In a word: no.
This is covered in the documentation:

If the 1GP and 2GP share a namespace, you can’t install them in the same org.

It doesn't matter if there's a dependency or not, you cannot do this because you cannot install both on the same org.
Based on questions in the comments, the following points should be noted:

A 1GP can have 2GP extension packages as long as the latter package(s) use a different namespace to the 1GP.
If the 1GP provides Apex-based services the 2GP(s) are to use, these must be made global so the 2GPs can access them.
The 2GP extension packages can all share the same namespace as each other but if they do, make sure to avoid name clashes. This can be done by providing a package-specific prefix used on all API names originating from that package. This prefixing approach applies to all classes, even those that are neither global nor @NamespaceAccessible since Salesforce does not scope name usage to the package, just to the namespace. Two 2GPs in the same namespace containing a same-named class cannot be installed together on a given org.


Hi Phil, ok, thanks a lot for the clarification. So what is the recommended approach to create the new package? Create it as a 2GP but with a different namespace? Or create it as a 1GP and convert it next year when the conversion tool is generally available?

For us, given the lead time until 1GP -> 2GP migration GAs, we created a new namespace for our 2GP extension packages. It is annoying, but fundamentally 1GP and 2GP have to have separate namespaces. Indeed, even with 1GP you have to use a different namespace (engineering multiple 1GPs with a shared namespace would be something of a challenge and if possible still would prevent same-org install!). I would not start with a new 1GP now, at all. I might think about simply adding the new stuff to the existing package if dependencies can be dynamic, or would use 2GP with new namespace.

Also, be aware that Apex classes and triggers must be uniquely named in each 2GP in a given namespace, even if they are non-global. This is a very annoying limitation, again covered in the collision documentation IIRC. We adopted package-specific name prefixes for classes, objects, fields, validation rules, flows etc. to avoid such collisions.

Hi Phil, thank you so much, this is so helpful! Just a last question, if I create now a 2GP with a different namespace, I need to change my apex classes from the current 1GP from public to global, if they are called from the new 2GP components, correct? Thank you!

That is correct @Mathilde. Again, a PITA, but you do what you have to!

Thank you so much for all your answers!

@Mathilde please upvote and/or mark the answer so later searches can see the answer was appropriate and to close off this question.
